# Create alias for a long path in webpack (typescript)

Tags: typescript, angular, webpack, aliases

I'm trying to create an alias for a long path in webpack but I can't find a working solution.

I've managed to find a snippet of what looked like the right solution, but it didn't worked.

I've added into webpack.dev.js into module.exports this:

```
resolve: {
    root: path.resolve('src/'),
    alias: {
        alias1: 'app/about',
        testino: 'app/testino/test',

    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
}
```

and import it in the app.component:

```
import {TestinoTest} from 'testino';
```

then I get error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./app.component" [WDS] Errors
>   while compiling. ./src/app/app.component.ts Module build failed:
>   Error: Cannot resolve module 'app/testino/test'

Path to that service is `src/app/testino/test/TestinoTest.service.ts`

Thanks in advance

**Solution:** (thanks to Bob Sponge)

in import there has to be the whole way from alias to the particular file

```
import {TestinoTest} from 'testino/TestinoTest.service.ts';
```

Comment: Relative paths to your code must be started with `./`. So, change `'app/testino/test'` to `'./app/testino/test'` in resolve.alias

Comment: And you must require appropriate file: `import {TestinoTest} from 'testino/TestinoTest.service.ts';`

Comment: Thank you @BobSponge, very much! :) That helped. I thought it's like "bundling". But it has to be without the `./` part

Comment: You can also add `'.ts'` to the list of `extensions` to be able to resolve the file without adding the extension expliclitly: `import {TestinoTest} from 'testino/TestinoTest.service';`